# Copying a file from one server to another server in same domain using vbscript

Tags: windows, vbscript

I am new to `Vb script`.
I need to copy a file from one server location to another server. I am using a code below:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strSourcePath = "D:\sample.txt"

strDestinationPath = "\\servername\D:\foldername\"

objFSO.CopyFile strSourcePath,strDestinationPath
```

But I am getting a "Path not found" error and i would like a message that file has been copied in a text file.

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The share name must be used on the destination path, eg. \\servername\d$\foldername\

D: is not a share, but d$ is an admin share.